# Unable to update number of rows count according to the selected array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all,Sorry for the lengthy codes given below.
Its because i am not able to figure out what am i missing or wrong

i want to display arrays in table view according to the button clicked..and when the user search..it should filter the tableview...everything works fine when i give a static 3 digit value in number of rows.otherwise the tableview is just blank.

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txtUser: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPhone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var SelectionView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var btnDawat: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnCountry: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnNationality: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var searchItems: UISearchBar!
    let manager = APIManager()

    var isSearching = Bool()

    enum options {
        case dawat
        case country
        case nationality
    }

    var lastSelection:options?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        isSearching = false

        manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.countries) { (JSON, Bool) in


            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let countries = dict!["data"] as! NSArray
            signUser.countries = countries as! [String]
            let nations = dict!["data"] as! NSArray
            signUser.nationalities  = nations as! [String]               

        }

            pickerTableView.reloadData()

    }


    @IBAction func DawatTitleSelectionAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        lastSelection = options.dawat
        pickerTableView.reloadData()
        SelectionView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)

    }

    @IBAction func CountrySelectionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        lastSelection = options.country
        pickerTableView.reloadData()
        SelectionView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)

    }

    @IBAction func NationalitySelectionAction(_ sender: UIButton){

        lastSelection = options.nationality
        pickerTableView.reloadData()
        SelectionView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)            
    }

    @IBAction func RegisterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


    //    Signup.email = self.txtEmail.text!
    //    Signup.phone = self.txtPhone.text!

    }

    @IBAction func pickerSelectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {            

        SelectionView.removeFromSuperview()            

    }        
}
```

//tableview and search function

```
    extension RegisterViewController : UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate  {


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

          print(signUser.tableData.count)

        return signUser.tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PickerTableViewCell

        if isSearching == false{
           // print("presenting raw data")

            switch lastSelection!{

            case .country:
              //  print("raw countries list")
                signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.countries
            case .nationality:
               // print("raw nationalities list")
                signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.nationalities
            case .dawat:
                signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.dawatTitles

            }

           signUser.tableData = signUser.unfilteredArray

         }

        else {
           // print("presenting filtered data")


            switch lastSelection!{

            case .country:
               // print("filtered countries")
                signUser.countries = signUser.filteredArray
                signUser.tableData = signUser.filteredArray
            case .nationality:
               // print("filtered nationalities")
                 signUser.nationalities = signUser.filteredArray
                signUser.tableData = signUser.filteredArray
            case .dawat:
                 signUser.dawatTitles = signUser.filteredArray
                signUser.tableData = signUser.filteredArray
            }

        }
            cell.lblTitle.text = signUser.tableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell            
    }


extension RegisterViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {


    //searchbar

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        signUser.filteredArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        if let searchText = searchItems.text, !searchText.isEmpty {

            isSearching = true

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)

            signUser.filteredArray = (signUser.unfilteredArray as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate) as! [String]


        }

        else {

            signUser.tableData = signUser.unfilteredArray
            isSearching = false

        }            

        pickerTableView.reloadData()            
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        isSearching = false

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the button action methods to change `signUser.tableData`

```
@IBAction func DawatTitleSelectionAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    lastSelection = options.dawat
    signUser.filteredArray = signUser.dawatTitles
    signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.dawatTitles
    signUser.tableData = isSearching ? signUser.filteredArray : signUser.unfilteredArray
    pickerTableView.reloadData()
    SelectionView.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)

}

@IBAction func CountrySelectionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    lastSelection = options.country
    signUser.filteredArray = signUser.countries
    signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.countries
    signUser.tableData = isSearching ? signUser.filteredArray : signUser.unfilteredArray
    pickerTableView.reloadData()
    SelectionView.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)

}

@IBAction func NationalitySelectionAction(_ sender: UIButton){

    lastSelection = options.nationality
    signUser.filteredArray = signUser.nationalities
    signUser.unfilteredArray = signUser.nationalities
    signUser.tableData = isSearching ? signUser.filteredArray : signUser.unfilteredArray
    pickerTableView.reloadData()
    SelectionView.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(SelectionView)
}
```

Update tableView delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(signUser.tableData.count)
    return signUser.tableData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PickerTableViewCell
    cell.lblTitle.text = signUser.tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Update searchbar delegate methods

```
extension RegisterViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            if let searchText = searchItems.text, !searchText.isEmpty {
                isSearching = true
                let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
                signUser.filteredArray = (signUser.unfilteredArray as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate) as! [String]
                signUser.tableData = signUser.filteredArray
            }
            else {
                signUser.tableData = signUser.unfilteredArray
                isSearching = false
            }
            pickerTableView.reloadData()
        }
        func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            isSearching = false
        }
}
```

Comment: pls check my code again..your code destroys my code logic on filtered array and i have used totally different method using enums

Comment: @JaseelCalicut your code logic isn't correct. Thats why I've changed it. You don't need to keep reference to the last selection and Don't change signUser.tableData inside cellForRowAt method

Comment: @JaseelCalicut check my answer

Comment: @JaseelCalicut  cell.lblTitle.text = signUser.tableData[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1):

- Use two arrays, the unfiltered and the filtered array for example

  ```
  var tableData = [Model]()
  var filteredArray = [Model]()
  ```

  and **never** replace `tableData` with filtered content.
- In `searchBar:textDidChange` filter the data by `lastSelection`, populate `filteredArray` and set `isSearching`.
- In the data source methods display the data depending on the state of `isSearching` (simplified)

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return isSearching ? filteredArray.count : tableData.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PickerTableViewCell
      let item : Model
      if isSearching {
         item = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
      } else {
         item = tableData[indexPath.row]
      }
      // assign the values of item to the UI
      return cell
  }
  ```

Comment: did'nt understand what you have written in numberofRows ..i dont think there is a code syntax like that.

Comment: *There **is** a code syntax like that*, it's called [Ternary Conditional Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71)